# Pandas Group by with dict values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with the following data:

```
size                   col1                   col2
1.5    {'val':1.1, 'id': 10}                  None
2.0    {'val':1.1, 'id': 11}                  None
3.0    {'val':1.1, 'id': 20}                  None
3.0                     None   {'val':1.1, 'id': 6}
```

I am trying to merge the rows and remove the `None` but when I do any `df.groupby(by=['size']).max()` or other it converts the dict values to NaN.

Is there a way to merge these rows and keep the dict values?

Expected Result:

```
size                   col1                   col2
1.5    {'val':1.1, 'id': 10}                  None
2.0    {'val':1.1, 'id': 11}                  None
3.0    {'val':1.1, 'id': 20}   {'val':1.1, 'id': 6}
```

The two (or more) rows sharing `size=3.0` are merged and the columns kept.

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: I have updated to add in expected result, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reading and testing it looks like pandas groupby agg functions can only work on numeric values. Any non-numeric values get dropped.

My solution required re-framing the whole problem, the new data format is:

```
size    col                  value
1.5    col1  {'val':1.1, 'id': 10}
2.0    col1  {'val':1.1, 'id': 11}
3.0    col1  {'val':1.1, 'id': 20}
3.0    col2   {'val':1.1, 'id': 6}
```

With this new data format I was able to use:

```
df = df.pivot(index='size',columns='col', values='value')
df = df.reset_index()
```

Using pivot preserves the dict values and since I was able to control the format of the date this solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby` with `first`

```
out = df.groupby('size').first()#.reset_index()
```

Update

```
out = df.replace({'None':np.nan}).groupby('size').first()#.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this only keeps the `col1` value and `col2`  is set to `None`. The various functions work if I dont have `dict` values, but I need the dict values in this case.

Comment: @Zexelon adding replace to None to NaN